# running yeoman angular generator, karma dependency error

Tags: npm, yeoman, karma-runner, yeoman-generator, nvm

I'm trying to run the `generator-angular` yeoman generator. But after installing and running it I get the following error

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-ng-scenario@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.6.2 wants karma@~0.10.0

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/harrymoreno/.nvm/v0.11.11/bin/node" "/Users/harrymoreno/.nvm/v0.11.11/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/harrymoreno/programming/js/temp
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.25
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/harrymoreno/programming/js/temp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

`npm list karma` returns

```
temp@0.0.0 /Users/harrymoreno/programming/js/temp
└── karma@0.12.0  peer invalid

npm ERR! peer invalid: karma@0.12.0 /Users/harrymoreno/programming/js/temp/node_modules/karma
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

so I think I have karma version 0.12.0 But grunt-karma wants 0.10.0 ?? I also install karma locally to my temp dir to see if that made a difference. It didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is karma@0.12.0 and grunt-karma@0.6.2 don't go hand in hand. The best way to deal with this problem is uninstall karma V 12 and install v 0.11.14 and grunt-karma@0.7.2

> $ npm uninstall karma grunt-karma
>
> $ npm install karma@0.11.14 grunt-karma@0.7.2

this should fix your problem.

Comment: any reason we don't uninstall and install globally here? just curious

Comment: I also ran into issues with `generator-karma` not being ~0.6.0 so I just gave generator-angular what it wanted by doing `npm install -g generator-karma@0.6.0` My takeaway being don't think too much and just give the module you're installing whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

I've also gotten such errors. I had karma installed globally.

So I removed it and run the `generator-angular` yeoman generator again.

It installed `karma@0.12.0` and `grunt-karma@0.8.0` and it seems to be all ok.